# How to remove null and consolidate two identitical rows into one

Tags: sql, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have a table xyz, with columns as id, key0 and value0.

Data:

| id | key0 | value0 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | type | Bachelors |
| 1 | sub_type | Computer science |
| 2 | type | Bachelors |
| 2 | sub_type | Biology |
| 3 | type | Masters |
| 3 | sub_type | Marine Enginnering |

I'm trying to join this table in another table, as such:

```
CASE
    WHEN xyz.key0 = 'type' THEN xyz.value0
  END AS TYPE,
CASE
   WHEN xyz.key0 = 'sub_type' THEN xyz.value0
  END AS SUB_TYPE
```

But the results are not what I want. I get results as such:

| id | Type | Sub_Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bachelors | Null |
| 1 | Null | Computer science |
| 2 | Bachelors | Null |
| 2 | Null | Biology |
| 3 | Masters | Null |
| 3 | Null | Marine Enginnering |

What I would rather like is :

| id | Type | Sub_Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bachelors | Computer science |
| 2 | Bachelors | Biology |
| 3 | Masters | Marine Enginnering |

So no data is duplicated, and is more nicer to look at too. Instead of having two rows, with the same data just.

Comment: Please don't forget to add DB2, Informix and Oracle to tags

Comment: Please show how you're doing the join.

Comment: [Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423302)

Comment: Here it is:
```from subjects sub
join xyz xyz on xyz.id = sub.id 
```

Comment: What's the expected result if an id has only one row, or three (or even more)?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN key0 ='type' THEN value0 END) AS Type,
    MAX(CASE WHEN key0 ='sub_type' THEN value0 END) AS Sub_Type
FROM
    xyz      
GROUP BY
    id
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do it using `group by` and `MAX CASE WHEN`

```
select id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN key0 = 'type' THEN value0 END) AS TYPE,
  MAX(CASE WHEN key0 = 'sub_type' THEN value0 END) AS SUB_TYPE
from mytable
group by id
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/WeHJP2NS)

Answer (score 0):

I would combine your code with Qwerty's code

```
select id,
MAX(Type) AS Type,
MAX(SUB_TYPE) AS Sub_Type
FROM
(
select id,
CASE
    WHEN xyz.key0 = 'type' THEN xyz.value0
  END AS TYPE,
CASE
   WHEN xyz.key0 = 'sub_type' THEN xyz.value0
  END AS SUB_TYPE
from subjects sub join xyz xyz on xyz.id = sub.id 
)x 
GROUP BY id
```

this will help eliminate the NULL values in the two columns

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  t1.id,
  t1.value0 AS type_value,
  t2.value0 AS sub_type_value
FROM original_table t1
INNER JOIN original_table t2
  ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE
  t1.key0 = 'type' AND t2.key0 = 'sub_type';
```

Thanks to @SelVazi for his demo. I used it to test my codes and results are attached below.

[image: Results]